Troubles with my female kitten
So I have a 7 months old female kitten who's now growing a lot and now starting to cause lots of trouble especially stealing fish and raw chicken from kitchen. I also have a 3 year old male cat but I swear I didn't have this kind of problem with him especially stealing food. Also kitten is usually aggressive towards my male cat and even forcefully takes away his food and the old fool doesn't even try to defend it. So is this how usually female cats behave or because she's still a kitten and being naughty? I'm worried if she becomes even more troublemaker after being adult.

is she spayed? a 7mo old cat is no longer a kitten and at this age she will get territorial if she is unspayed.

No. My both cats aren't sterile and the male cat doesn't seen interested in her. The kitten is always causing trouble especially takes away my old cat's food on purpose and even from my own kitchen

Fair warning: You need to spay / neuter at least one of them or you will absolutely end up with kittens. Once the female goes into heat, she will produce strong sex hormones that the male will not be able to withstand. Her heat can last from one to several weeks and you will have to keep them separate at all times during that time, else she will get pregnant.

In addition to the guarantee of kittens if she's not spayed, female cats in heat can be extremely loud while trying to draw the attention of a male. That said, her behavior is not an indicator of whether or not she's actually fertile, a mistake my family made with a cat who was scheduled to be spayed but ended up with a litter.

Is your young cat free fed or fed frequently?  The simplest explanation for excessive food "theft" in a cat under a year is just that she is still growing and very hungry.  You may need to increase her calories and that could help.  (You might also just have to make human food harder to reach/steal by placing a heavy lid or bowl.  Some cats don't care and others love it.)

Where did you get the kitten? If she started as a feral, she is likely to be food - insecure, at least until she learns that the humans will feed her reliably.

First and foremost I would have her spayed or you will have kittens. she is able to get pregnant now . Her behavior is very normal for a female kitten reaching her breeding age. I would recommend spraying her with a water bottle when she tries to steal food. and for now i would make sure your male cat has a space away from her that he can feel free to eat. once she is spayed her behavior should calm and disappear.
